# How I can return an ArrayList from a listener

Tags: java, android, firebase

I don't know how I can pass to other class the list that `resultado.toObject(TasksList.class).getTasks()` returns

```
public void getTasks() {
        userTasks.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot resultado = task.getResult();
                    if (resultado.exists()) {
                        TasksList list = new TasksList();
                        List<ToDoModel> tasks = resultado.toObject(TasksList.class).getTasks();
                        //Use the the list
                        for (ToDoModel entry : tasks) {
                            list.addTask(entry);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("debug", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "how I can pass to another class"?

Comment: I mean that I want to return the lista outside the listener, if I could to return it threw the function It wold be perfect, but I think that it's not possible

Comment: You cannot return a list as a result of an asynchronous operation. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a custom callback or using Kotlin Coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't alter the method to return the list, you could use a setter on the other object to set the value before the method ends

```
                   if (resultado.exists()) {
                        TasksList list = new TasksList();
                        List<ToDoModel> tasks =  
                        resultado.toObject(TasksList.class).getTasks();
                        //Use the the list
                        for (ToDoModel entry : tasks) {
                            list.addTask(entry);
                        }

                        theOtherObject.setList(list);

                    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I have declared a final list out of the listener and I've call to the setter inside, but the list is empty

Comment: What? Do you mean that the TasksList list is declared as "final"?

Comment: If I want to use an external variable inside the listener It must be final

Comment: Then set it to an internal variable inside the object. Instead of 
theOtherObject.setList(list);
use this.setList(list);

Comment: But I want to return the list outside the listener, that's my problem, that I don't know if it is possible

Comment: You can call a method inside the class, which can hold a reference to the other class and set it through there:

this.setListOnOtherClass(list);

and in the method setListOnOtherClass() you could have:
theOtherObject.setList(list);